# Issues in creating audit table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `client_property` and another table with similar structure called `client_property_version`.
What I am trying to do is, whenever someone updates a row in the `client_property` table, the entire row before update should get inserted in the `client_property_version` so that I may have something like an audit table. I have tried to do something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER client_property_audit BEFORE UPDATE ON client_property
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO `client_property_version` select * from client_property where property_id = OLD.property_id;
END;
```

but it is throwing syntax error. Can anyone suggest me a better way to do the same?
PS: I am not keeping any unique column in the `client_property_version` table.

Comment: What error do you get? Did you define another delimiter around the trigger definition?

Comment: `MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3 `

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set another delimiter than `;`, then the statement will end at the first `;` and your trigger definition will be incomplete. You need to tell *MySQL* that the statement should end at the delimiter you defined. After that you can set the delimiter back with `delimiter ;`

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER client_property_audit BEFORE UPDATE ON client_property
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   INSERT INTO `client_property_version` 
   select * from client_property where property_id = OLD.property_id;
END;
|
delimiter ;
```